# Why am I getting 'bodyParser' is deprecated warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I used the latest version of both packages but still, I am getting 'bodyParser' is a deprecated warning. It is not affecting my code but why is this happening?

```
const express =  require("express")
const bodyParser =  require("body-parser")

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Welcome to ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: What is the EXACT error message?  When does the error appear (on startup, when processing a request)?  What version of the body-parser module?  What version of Express?  When I run this same code with Express v4.17.1 and body-parser v1.19.0, I do not get any such warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that body-parser want you to use a different method (.json() or .urlencoded()):

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to not use body-parser anymore

Since Express 4.16+ the body parsing functionality has become built into express

You can do

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

from directly express, without having to install body-parser.

so you can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`, and use the above with express

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occur to my projects also .
Now in latest express we don't need to import body-parse, we can just use express as follow.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

or
if you limit size

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: false, parameterLimit: 500000000 }));
```